# Memory Corruption error in production

Tags: c#, c

I am using a third party c lib wrapped in a c# .net 4. When I run the application it crashes with memory corruption error.

I don't get this error in debug or release build if "Enable managed coding debugging is enabled" in visual studio 2013.

Also when do live debugging with application verifier and gflag it does not give me any error however when I take application of out of Image File Execution Options it crashes again.

Any idea how can I debug or fix this issue.

Comment: I would start with a debugger to debug.

Comment: it works fine in the debugger.

Comment: If you get errors without, it does **not** "work fine in the debugger"! It is just that you do not notice the problem. Think about the implications of **undefined** _behaviour_.

Comment: It does not indicate any undefined behaviour, it just says critical error detected c0000374, exe has triggered a breakpoint.  first Chance exception at .... : a heap has been corrupted and carry on normal. I don't have code to API to debug which is causing this error.

Comment: Huh? First you wrote "it works fine", now you wrte you get a critical error. And how would you _define_ **undefined behaviour**?

Comment: This  happens when we run the app without debugger in VS or application verifier or gflag etc. If we run in debugger in VS with enable managed code debugging checked or in app verifier then it works fine. so i am kinda stuck how to debug this.